# How to implement sound captcha using jcaptcha library?

Tags: java, captcha, servlet-3.0

I started using `jcaptcha library` to implement a simple image based `captcha` for my project and it went well, working fine. But now I want to integrated sound `captcha` functionality also along with `image captcha`. Please give me a walk through of how I can implement it using `jcaptcha` library in `Java`.

Here is code snippet I worked on :

```
//captcha engine config 

public class CustomCaptchaEngine extends ListImageCaptchaEngine {

@Override
protected void buildInitialFactories() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    WordGenerator wordGen=new RandomWordGenerator("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwzxyz0123456789");

    RandomRangeColorGenerator colorGen=new RandomRangeColorGenerator(new int[]{100,255},new int[]{50,200}, new int[]{50,150});

    TextPaster textPaster = new RandomTextPaster(new Integer(4), new Integer(5), colorGen, Boolean.TRUE);

    BackgroundGenerator backgroundGenerator = new FileReaderRandomBackgroundGenerator(new Integer(200), new Integer(100), "C:/Users/pandabhi/eclipseworkspace/CaptchaTest/WebContent/captcha_backgrounds/");

    Font[] fontsList = new Font[] { new Font("Arial", Font.TYPE1_FONT, 10), new Font("Arial", 0, 14), new Font("Vardana", 0, 17), };

    FontGenerator fontGenerator = new RandomFontGenerator(20, 50, fontsList);

    WordToImage wordToImage=new ComposedWordToImage(fontGenerator, backgroundGenerator, textPaster);

    this.addFactory(new GimpyFactory(wordGen, wordToImage));
}

}


//captcha servlet 

public class ImageCaptchaServlet extends HttpServlet {


/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {

    super.init(servletConfig);

}


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {

   byte[] captchaChallengeAsJpeg = null;
   // the output stream to render the captcha image as jpeg into
    ByteArrayOutputStream jpegOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
    // get the session id that will identify the generated captcha.
    //the same id must be used to validate the response, the session id is a good candidate!
    String captchaId = httpServletRequest.getSession().getId();
    // call the ImageCaptchaService getChallenge method
        BufferedImage challenge =
                CaptchaServiceInstance.getInstance().getImageChallengeForID(captchaId,
                        httpServletRequest.getLocale());

        // a jpeg encoder
        ImageIO.write(challenge, "jpg", jpegOutputStream);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
        return;
    } catch (CaptchaServiceException e) {
        httpServletResponse.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        return;
    }

    captchaChallengeAsJpeg = jpegOutputStream.toByteArray();

    // flush it in the response
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    httpServletResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
    httpServletResponse.setContentType("image/jpeg");
    ServletOutputStream responseOutputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
    responseOutputStream.write(captchaChallengeAsJpeg);
    responseOutputStream.flush();
    responseOutputStream.close();
}
}

//captcha service instance 

public class CaptchaServiceInstance {

     private static ImageCaptchaService instance = 
                new DefaultManageableImageCaptchaService( new FastHashMapCaptchaStore(),new CustomCaptchaEngine(), 180,100000,75000);


public static ImageCaptchaService getInstance(){
    return instance;
}
}
```

Comment: What have tried? Your post could be improved if you included what code you're currently tried. Also, SO prohibits people from asking for outside resources such as walk thoughts or tutorials.

Comment: thanks for suggestion @richard . added code for more details.

Comment: Thanks. Also, I edited your code's formatting (which won't show up until my edit is reviewed). Code blocks are formatted with four spaces. The backticks are only used for incline formatting (SO's formatting can be tricky at first).

Comment: Thanks again for edit. I'll really appreciate if you could help me in implementing sound captcha.

Comment: Thanks everyone for correcting me at each step. I have successfully implemented it and its working great. :)

Comment: @AbhinayaPandey your sound captcha reproduce the same tex from the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Captcha sound generator
//remember to change Voice.java file's deallocation() method as it was creating problems while compilation.Rebuild freetts source and use that.

public class CustomSoundCaptchaService {
private static SoundCaptchaService instanceSound=null;

public static SoundCaptchaService getInstance(WordGenerator wordGen){

     SoundConfigurator soundConfig = new FreeTTSSoundConfigurator("kevin16", "com.sun.speech.freetts.en.us.cmu_us_kal.KevinVoiceDirectory", 1.0f, 100, 100);

     WordToSound word2sound = new FreeTTSWordToSound(soundConfig,6,7);

     CaptchaFactory[] factories = new CaptchaFactory[]{new GimpySoundFactory(wordGen, word2sound)};

     CaptchaEngine captchaEngine = new GenericCaptchaEngine(factories);

     instanceSound = new GenericManageableCaptchaService(captchaEngine, 180,180000, 75000);
     return instanceSound;
     }
}



//invoking servlet 
public class SoundCaptchaServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public SoundCaptchaServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    AudioInputStream audioCaptcha=null;
    try {
        String captchaId = request.getSession().getId();
        WordGenerator wordGen= new RandomWordGenerator("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwzxyz0123456789");
        audioCaptcha=CustomSoundCaptchaServlet.getInstance(worGen).getSoundChallengeForID(captchaId);

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (CaptchaServiceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    response.setContentType("audio/mpeg");
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream soundByteOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    AudioSystem.write(audioCaptcha,javax.sound.sampled.AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE,soundByteOutputStream);
    out.write(soundByteOutputStream.toByteArray());
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

//replace existing code in Voice.java with following
public void deallocate() {
setLoaded(false);
utteranceProcessors.clear();

    if (!externalAudioPlayer) {
        if (audioPlayer != null) {
            audioPlayer.close();
            audioPlayer = null;
        }
    }

if (!externalOutputQueue) {

}
}
```